# Update product quantities in Prestashop from command line

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have created a module in Prestashop 1.7.6 which update products stocks by 2 ways :

- In the back office (the settings of the module) it works perfectly
- From a cron by the server every night using a declared service called by this kind of command line :

  php /var/www/MyPrestashopSite/bin/console mymodule:update updateProducts --no-debug

For many other services that I have created and I use it works perfectly, but for this one, I use the "new" stock management in Prestashop, and when I use the \StockAvailable methods, it always call the Context and trigger an error of StockManagementRepository line 130 : **'Determining the active language requires a contextual employee instance.'**
This error prevent my module from updating product stock out of Context.

In my code I tried to use the following methods, to get and modify the stock in the cleanest possible way :

```
\StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct(...)
\StockAvailable::setQuantity(...)
\StockAvailable::updateQuantity(...)
```

Note that I force the $shopId to 1 to avoid getting the Context as much as possible.

Do you know how to update a stock in a clean way (not just modifying the stocks, product attributes and products tables) in Prestashop from a cron (out of the context and without employee connexion), and without calling the Prestashop webservice ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to specify a FronTController or a .php file for cron and make the changes in it.

In case of a .php file, you should include the PrestaShop config file.
For example, if your file is inside your module folder:
modules/mymodulename/cron/stock-update.php

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../config/config.inc.php';
//do the stuff
```

And thanks to the config.inc.php, you can use the Context object as well

```
$context = Context::getContext();
```

And you can even set the employee in the context menu by

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->employee = new Employee($idEmployee);
```

Answer (score 0):

using a FrontController in a module solve the issue.
Can see "Using a front controller as a cron task" in  https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/